# Domain and range of $f(x) = -1 + \sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $f(x) = -1 + \sqrt{x+2}$

$$Dom(f(x)) = \{x|x\geq-2\}$$

$$Ran(f(x)) = \{y|y\geq-1\}$$

To see that the range is, all of the set above, it needs to be shown that for $y\geq-1$ there exists a real number x such that,

$$y = -1 +\sqrt{x+2}$$

Solving for x we have,

$$y+1 = \sqrt{x+2} \\
x+2 = (y+1)^2 \\
x = (y+1)^2 - 2 $$

this shows that the domain is the all the set $\{y|y\geq -1\}$

Is this correct? 
Also, is any of my notation incorrect or can it be improved?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step missing in the end is to check that $f((y+1)^2-2) = y$ when $y\geq -1$, as Siong Thye Goh points out. This is important, since if $y<-1$, $f((y+1)^2-2) = -y-2$, actually!

To be more clear what I mean, you basically wrote: "if $y = -1 + \sqrt{x+2}$ has a solution for some $y$, then that solution is $x = (y+1)^2-2$", but you didn't comment that in the case $y<-1$ there is no solution and you didn't check that in the case $y\geq -1$ there really exists a solution (as I wrote in the 1st paragraph).

Thus, your phrasing is not as clear as it could be.

Here's one alternative approach to be more precise. As soon as you wrote $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$, it is implicit that by this you mean a bijective function $[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$, inverse to $x\mapsto x^2\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$.

Let's define $g(x) = -1 + x$, $h(x) = \sqrt x$ and $k(x) = x + 2$. Then, $f = g\circ h\circ k$ and the range of $f$ is

$$f([-2,\infty)) = g(h(k([-2,\infty)))= g(h([0,\infty))) = g([0,\infty)) = [-1,\infty).$$

Comment: "This is important, since if $y<−1, f((y+1)2−2)=−y−2$, actually!" I do not understand this at all? How do you get $=-y - 2$ by substituting $x = (y+1)^2 - 2$ into f(x)?

Comment: so that last few lines when you are using function composition is actually another technique to find the range of $f(x)$?

Comment: @Bucephalus, it's because $\sqrt{(y+1)^2} = |y+1|$, which is not equal to $y+1$ unless $y\geq -1$. For $y<-1$, $|y+1| = -y-1$. For your second question, in the last few lines we are assuming that domains and ranges of $g$, $h$ and $k$ are known, so we are just applying this in succession to arrive at the result.

Comment: why are we assuming that the domain and range are known? isn't it obvious that the domain and range of $k$ is all the real numbers? Or are you taking into account that the range of $h$ constrains the domain of $k$?

Comment: @Bucephalus, sorry, I should have been more precise in what I mean. We are using that for $m$ monotonically increasing continuous function, $m([a,b]) = [m(a),m(b)]$, and if $m$ is unbounded, $m([a,\infty)) = [m(a),\infty)$. In these simple examples you can just show this by hand, but in the future, you may need this more general statement.

Comment: Thankyou @Ennar

Answer (score 1):

Your working is fine.

It should be clear that $(y+1)^2-2 \ge -2$ and it is in the domain and if $y \ge -1$, then we have.

$$-1 + \sqrt{(y+1)^2-2+2}=y.$$

Now the question is what if $y<-1$? Is it possible to have a preimage? We know it doesn't because $$-1+\sqrt{x+2}\ge -1$$

Comment: I do not think i'm following you. Are you saying that in my last line of working I should explicitly indicate that$(y+1)^2-2 \ge -2 $. Further to show it is in the domain, is that why you have substituted $(y+1)^2-2$ back into the original equation? And if that equation is true, y = y, then it is true that it is in the domain?

Comment: Suppose you are given another function, $g: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, suppose another person ask is $-1$ is in the range of $g$? The answer should  be no. We can tell this by checking whether our preimage is always in the domain of a function.

Comment: Thankyou @SiongThyGoh